# How can you receive an image sent from Android using WCF?

Tags: c#, android, wcf

If you have a simple example of how you can receive an image using WCF and save that image in a custom folder, they would save me a lot of time and guide me on the right track.

I've seen that you can use the ***Stream*** type or the ***byte[]*** type, but I could not do it correctly.

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a demo, wish it is useful to you.
**Server (WCF service application)**

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method ="POST",RequestFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json,ResponseFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        Task UploadStream(Stream stream);

    }
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public async Task UploadStream(Stream stream)
        {
            using (stream)
            {
                //save file to local folder
                using (var file=File.Create(@"C:\"+Guid.NewGuid().ToString()+".png"))
                {
                    await stream.CopyToAsync(file);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

**Web.config(wcf configuration)**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService3.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService3.IService1" bindingConfiguration="mybinding" behaviorConfiguration="rest"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="mybinding" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="104857600" transferMode="Streamed">
          <security mode="None"></security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="rest">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

For creating stream transfer mode service, we could also create soap service with BasicHttpBinding.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/02733eae-a871-4655-9a2b-0ca1095b07ea/problems-when-uploading-a-stream-to-wcf?forum=wcf
On client end, you could use third-party library to call the WCF rest service, such as ksoap. But you also could send a http request with HttpClient library. Just like the following code snippets (HttpClient is .Net library, not java library, but the usage is similar).

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpContent content = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(@"2.png"));
        Task.WaitAll(client.PostAsync("http://10.157.18.36:8800/service1.svc/UploadStream", content));
        Console.WriteLine("OK");
    }
}
```

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: in fact, this demo is a good example, because it gives the asynchrony approach, thank you very much for sharing it

Answer (score 0):

You want to consume an image response from a WCF endpoint?
An example here:
https://www.dotnetcurry.com/wcf/723/download-files-using-wcf-rest-endpoints

Comment: Actually, that's the next step, thanks for sharing. However it's the other way, an Android app will send to the WCF service an image file, and thtat's where I'm stuck